# Streaming converted movie with mp4 container in NodeJS, movie playing very fast

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, mp4, webm

I have used [stream-transcoder](https://github.com/trenskow/stream-transcoder.js) module to convert a file make it a stream. So the file is not stored, it is on the fly.

```
app.get("/video", function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'});
    var src = "movie.avi";

    var Transcoder = require('stream-transcoder');
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(src);
    new Transcoder(stream)
        .maxSize(1280, 720)
        .videoCodec('h264')
        .videoBitrate(800 * 1000)
        .fps(25)
        .sampleRate(44100)
        .channels(2)
        .audioBitrate(128 * 1000)
        .format('mp4')
        .on('finish', function() {
            console.log("finished");
        })
        .stream().pipe(res);
});
```

It works nicely, it is fast, but too fast, the audio is played at the same speed, however the video does not respect the frame rate, whatever is recieved from ffmpeg is immeidately shown, fastly. Additionally, it does not show the total time, I believe it is the problem. I need to somehow specify the length, framerate, but I could not find enough information on that. I thought the stream recieved from ffmpeg should contain that. And I could not find respective headers for that in HTTP.

Here are the flags that this stream-transcoder module uses for MP4:

```
[ '-i',
  '-',
  '-vf',
  'scale=min(trunc(1280/hsub)*hsub\\,trunc(a*720/hsub)*hsub):min(trunc(720/vsub)*vsub\\,trunc(1280/a/vsub)*vsub)',
  '-vcodec',
  'h264',
  '-b:v',
  800000,
  '-r',
  25,
  '-ar',
  44100,
  '-ac',
  2,
  '-ab',
  128000,
  '-f',
  'mp4',
  '-movflags',
  'frag_keyframe+faststart',
  'pipe:1' ]
```

When I use VP8 encoder and WebM, it works nicely, the time is displayed, video plays normal speed.

Comment: it could happens if PTS are incorrect, look at what -genpts does !

Comment: @alexbuisson I used  `-fflags +genpts` but no help

Comment: It seems it works on Chromecast on TV, but not on Chrome itself, strange.

Comment: the same is happening to me, it seems to be related with nodejs and that process the data to fast or something like that, i just copy and paste the output of the stream-transcoder and run by myself in terminal output to test.mp4 file and the video runs as it should

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to add "-re" flag to the ffmpeg command when streaming from a file on the fly like you are describing.

Check out there guide here: [FFmpeg Streaming Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide)

Here is the direct ffmpeg command for streaming a file to a location.

`ffmpeg -re -i 'myfile.mp4' -vcodec libx264 -b:v 950k -r 24 -s 1024x576 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 64k -f flv 'rtmp://mywowzaserver.com/live/mp4:streamName'`

Comment: Sorry, it did not help

Comment: Here is what I use on a local system to stream a local file to a wowza server.  Maybe you can find some differences in your flag breakdown and mine since ultimately its still ffmpeg.

`ffmpeg -re -i 'myfile.mp4' -vcodec libx264 -b:v 950k -r 24 -s 1024x576 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 64k -f flv 'rtmp://mywowzaserver.com/live/mp4:streamName'`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the problem lies in that fact that you are not declaring the AAC audio codec (which is generally speaking required for compliant h264 video). The sample code on that github page does this explicitly:

```
"        .audioCodec('libfaac') "
```

If you continue to have problems, you should open an issue at the Github page:

https://github.com/trenskow/stream-transcoder.js/issues

EDIT
You also did not specify

```
-profile:v baseline -level 3.0
```

which is probably why it works on chromecast and not chrome.

Comment: Adding it did not fix it, the problem is with video, it is not played in normal speed, whatever in the buffer is just shown.

Comment: have you checked with a different file?

Comment: Yes I did, no difference

Comment: See my edit. It is probably the reason why it works some places and not in other ones. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide#Compatibility

Comment: It still plays the video faster.